# How to go back into previously visited folder in vim :Explore?

Tags: vim

Sometimes I need to go back into previously visited folder (not a parent folder), let's take example:

```
:Explore
# we at /home/project
../
./
foo/
bar/
file

# now I press -, hence go to the parent directory /home

../
./
project/

# now I press - again, hence go to the root /

../
./
bin/
boot/
etc

# and here is the question..
```

How to go back into initial `project/` directory. I expected something like `bb` where b is go back to the previous state. Is the way to do it?

Comment: Does `<c-o>` work? (ie. go back in the jump stack)

Comment: Yeaa! F*cking great!) Post it as an answer. Where did you find it?

Comment: `<c-i>` also do go forward!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the standard ways of jumping around in vim is with the jump list. From `:h jumplist`

```
                                                        jumplist
Jumps are remembered in a jump list.  With the CTRL-O and CTRL-I command you
can go to cursor positions before older jumps, and back again.  Thus you can
move up and down the list.
```

I recommend reading the whole section to learn more.

For your use case using `<c-o>` should bring you back to the previous buffer in netrw.